# ANTLR 4 / Parser recognizes erroneous expression as valid

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Grammar file Expr.g4:

```
grammar Expr;

expr:   expr ('*'|'/'|'+'|'-'|'%') expr 
    |   '(' expr ')'
    |   INT 
    ;

INT :   [0-9]+ ;
WS  :   [ \t\n]+ -> skip ;
```

I use the current ANTLR-Version 4.7.1:
In ./bashrc:

```
alias antlr4='java -jar ~/antlr4/antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar'
alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig'
```

With this grammar the expression '1(' shouldn't be recognized as valid,
but it is.

`grun Expr expr -tokens` on the command line with input '1(' and CTRL-D for EOF gives:

```
[@0,0:0='1',<INT>,1:0]

[@1,1:1='(',<'('>,1:1]

[@2,2:1='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:2]
```

While the expression '1(' is not rejected, ')1' is:

```
[@0,0:0=')',<')'>,1:0]

[@1,1:1='1',<INT>,1:1]

[@2,2:1='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:2]

line 1:0 extraneous input ')' expecting {'(', INT}
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke a rule in ANTLR, it successfully returns a result as long as it can match any prefix of the input. If you want a rule to only succeed if it matches the entire remaining input, you'll need to add `EOF` as the last token.

However, you don't want to add `EOF` to the `expr` rule because you also use that rule to match sub-expressions. So instead you should define another rule that's just `expr EOF` and invoke that one with `grun`.

Comment: Thank you :-), I added a new rule 'start : expr EOF ;' works like a charm.